# Nivo Slider have javascript error

Tags: javascript, slider, nivo-slider

I'm building a website which use Nivo Slider. At first, it worked nicely. But yesterday, when I tried again, it's suddenly stop moving. I haven't changed anything yet before I discovered this issue. I looked into the console and there is a javascript error which says:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'

When I tried to look into jquery.nivo.slider.js, the error is on $('a.nivo-prevNav', slider) like below:

```
$('a.nivo-prevNav', slider).live('click', function(){
    // function's content
});
```

Using google's inspect element feature, I search into the page and found  there.

What is wrong with that? why it is suddenly stop moving? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Nivo Slider needs jQuery to work. On your website you refer to jQuery like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

This is pretty dangerous, as the latest version constantly changes. As can be seen from the jQuery documentation at

http://api.jquery.com/live/

the live function is deprecated since jQuery 1.7. Looking at the unminified jQuery source at

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

it seems like the function is not there anymore, which is why you get the error.

Solution: bind jQuery with a specific version - probably you can find out which version you need from Nivo Slider documentation. Some of the older versions of jQuery can be found here: http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution!! I shouldn't have referred to the latest jquery like that. I'm using jQuery 1.6 now and it works. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery version 1.9, which it looks like you're using, the `live()` function is actually deprecated: http://api.jquery.com/live/

I guess you may have to wait for Nivo to update their source to support the latest jQuery, you can go down to jQuery 1.7, or modify the Nivo source yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a new version of Nivo Slider (3.2) that uses .on instead of .live.

Or use an older version of jQuery (1.7.1 is working for us)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing all the .live() with .on() in the nivo slider's js file worked for me. My jquery was version 1.9.1 .